# $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2abc\left(a+b+c\right) \geq 3\left(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a\right)$

Tags: inequality, triangles, sum-of-squares-method

Let: $a,b,c >0$. Prove that:

$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2abc\left(a+b+c\right) \geq 3\left(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a\right)$$

I read an ugly solution:

Take $LHS-RHS$, get:

$$\sum\left(-ab+ac-5bc\right)\left(a-b\right)^2 \geq 0$$

It is by Maple, but how can a person solve this? Thanks

Comment: No, check a=1, b=1, c=2.

Comment: For any triangle the reversed inequality is true.

Comment: From Muirhead's inequality, the reverse direction is true, so it can't be that this one true, as others commented.

Comment: Can you show me the solution please! @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: I don't think so @V.S.e.H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is wrong.

Try $a=b=1$ and $c\rightarrow0^+$.

The reversed inequality is true for any triangle.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)\geq a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+2abc(a+b+c),$$ which is true because
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^3b-a^2b^2-2a^2bc)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(6a^3b-2a^2b^2-4a^2bc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(3a^3b+3a^3c-6a^2b^2+4a^2b^2-4a^2bc+3a^3b-3a^3c)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(3ab(a-b)^2+2c^2(a-b)^2+3(a+b+c)(a^2b-a^2c))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3ab+2c^2)-(a+b+c)(a-b)^3)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3ab+2c^2-a^2+b^2-ac+bc)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c^2-a^2+b^2)$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(c^2-a^2+b^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious and
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the inequality is wrong in the given direction. However, it is true in the reverse direction.

Let $f(a,b,c) = \sum_{cyc} 3a^3b -a^2b^2- 2a^2bc$, and assume $a$ is the largest wlog, since $f$ is cyclic. If $c > b$ then
$$
f(a,c,b) - f(a,b,c)= 3(a^3c - a^3b + c^3b-b^3c+b^3a-c^3a)=3(a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)\geq 0,
$$
thus we can assume wlog that $a\geq b\geq c$.
By Muirhead we have
$$
2\sum_{cyc}a^2bc\leq\sum_{sym}a^3b\leq 2\sum_{cyc}a^3b,
$$
and
$$
\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}a^2b^2\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}a^3b\leq\sum_{cyc}a^3b,
$$
thus $f(a,b,c)\geq 0$.